# Appium, Android - using selenium VB wrapper unable to switch to WEBVIEW

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am currently using Appium 1.4.16.1 on Windows to automate an Android Hybrid App using the Selenium VB Wrapper - http://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/.

I face problem trying to automate tests for the WebView.
I have read solutions online related to switching context to the WEBVIEW.
However, using the selenium vb wrapper, i have not been able to achieve. It seems like switch context is not supported by the vb wrapper.

If i know that the screen contains a webview, is there a way to directly tell appium to switch context to the web view? eg: sending a http request or executing a javascript?

Thanks.
Bipo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone has the same problem...
You can use the Driver.Send enhancement added to SeleniumBasic v2.0.8.0
Example:
driver.Send "POST", "/context", "name", "WEBVIEW"